# Design a MultiplyByThree circuit using one 4-bit adder

Tags: logic, cpu-architecture, multiplication, boolean-logic

Design a MultiplyByThree circuit using one 4-bit adder. A 4-bit adder is a circuit that performs the addition of two number consisting of 4 bits each. Additionally, you have a half adder, it is a circuit that performs the addition of two numbers consisting of one bit each. Assume that we have already manufactured 4-bit adder and half adder shown below.

I'm having trouble finding the answer to this using a theoretical 4-bit adder and one half adder. The only solution I could find was using 2 full-adders and 2 half-adders and even that I'm not sure of. The image below is my attempt at solving it using the conditions given in the question. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yvdD.jpg)

Comment: Make use of `3X = 2X + X`

Comment: ... and notice that you can produce 2X without using any logic gates at all

Comment: The sketch looks perfectly valid, while using more hardware than necessary for a delay from *A₀* to *S₅* avoidably high. Given the allowance presented and not assuming a trick question, that may well be what is expected. Surprise them by usurping the half adder and just using the n-bit adder with carry out, exploiting *S₀ = A₀*: this reduces total delay to just the adder delay.